# Why is "use custom server" option disabled in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have DotnetNuke loaded in Visual studio 2010. The 'use custom server' option under 'Start Options' is disabled. Why is it disabled? 
What does 'Use Default Web server' default to? How do I change what the default is?
In earlier versions of VS i was able to switch between IIS and the internal web server (Cassini). Now it's more confusing in VS 2010!

Would the project type, Web Application Project vs Web Site project, affect the setting?

Answer (score 18):

I've just had this problem on one of my projects that was setup to use IIS Express.

The solution for me was to right click the web site project and select the option to use the VS Server instead.  The option to then use a custom server was then enabled again so I could point it to the IIS site I wanted to test against.

Comment: yep same exact thing for me on  vs 2012 server 2012.  annoying.  need to get rid of iis express...

Comment: How do you do this with a web application (no project file)? There is no such option for me in VS 2010

Comment: Yes, right click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Use Visual Studio Development Server" seem to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Just had this issue as well today with Visual Studio 2012.  Another solution is open VS (without any project loading) and then File > Open Web Site.   Select the web site you're having problems with.   At that point VS will warn that another server is configured to be used for this site.  If you select 'No' in the dialog, you can then use Property Pages to set a custom server as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have all these options working just fine on my machine, and I've tried it with quite a lot of solutions, web applications, and web projects. It worked everywhere...

In your case I think it might either be a permissions issue, or some problem with the installation..

What version of VS do you have installed? Web developer? Pro? Ultimate?
Did it throw any errors during installation?

Are you sure Cassini is installed and available on your machine?

Also, you could try running VS as admin. Sure, it should still work without it (and it does, trust me :P ), but it might help find out the problem...

**UPD:** Which os do you have, and is it 32/64 bit?

What exe files do you have in these folders?

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0

Comment: It's VS 2010 ultimate in Win7 64 bit. The installation didn't throw any errors. I have WebDev.WebServer20 & WebDev.WebServer40. VS runs under administrator.

Comment: This is just weird then.. Sorry, can't come up with any ideas :(